Matrix Workspaces stop working on Ubuntu 22.04
I've use this GNOME extension for years without issue, and today out of nowhere it just stopped working. I purged and re-installed the Chrome Shell Integration extension as well as chrome-gnome-shell following
https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeShellIntegration/Installation?action=show&redirect=Projects%2FGnomeShellIntegrationForChrome%2FInstallation
but nothing changes. I can switch on the extension on Chrome but does nothing and as soon as I refresh the page, it shows as off again. The extensions page says this at the top

Your native host connector do not support following APIs: v6. You
should probably upgrade native host connector or install plugins for
missing APIs. Refer to the documentation for instructions.

where the documentation is the same page as above. But there's nothing more in there about getting to work.
Did anybody experienced this or something similar recently?

Check Chrome support and see if they still support this extension.
